# Why do we 'jump' when we push the ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

As a scenario say, If we suddenly push the ground and release the pressure we will jump off but where does the force coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Newton's 3rd Law states:

> whenever two objects interact, they exert equal and opposite forces on each other

When jumping, Just before you leave the ground, you would exert a force on the ground, then due to the 3rd Law, an equal an opposite force would be applied by the ground on you and due to this you are able to jump.

In fact, this is the reason you can walk, run, ride a cycle, etc. In all these applications, the ground exerts a force, providing acceleration, because an equal force was applied on it.